# Revert mongorestore changes

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

Is there a way of reverting changes of mongorestore command? I couldn’t find anything useful in the docs. I’ve done it accidentally on a wrong local db instance.

Comment: This very much depends on what specifically you mean by "revert", what options you specified when running mongorestore, and whether or not the data contained in the restore would conflict with the data already in the database

Comment: Could be difficult unless you have made a backup beforehand

Comment: @Joe just mongorestore in dump folder directory without any options. By revert i mean removing everything that was added by mongorestore.

Answer (score 0):

If the data added by mongorestore did not use the same database and collection names as the data in the mongod, you can read those names from the directory/filenames in the dump directory and drop them from the mongod.

If it did use the same names, you will likely need to use an earlier backup.